# FullCalendar 5 - How to show a coloured dot to the left of events in initialView: 'timeGridWeek' instead of solid fill

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

When I set the FullCalendar to:

```
initialView: 'dayGridWeek',
```

The Events are shown with coloured dots instead of solid fill (this is what I want). However, when I set the FullCalendar to:

```
initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
```

the Events appear as solid fill. How can I correct this please (i.e., show a coloured dot to the left of each Event)?

My code is:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    firstDay: 0, //Sunday
    weekends: true, //Show the weekends
    businessHours: { // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
        daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Friday
        startTime: '09:00', // a start time
        endTime: '17:00', // an end time
    },
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
    },
    locale: 'en-gb',
    selectable: true, // gives ability to select multiple days and then have a callback event when this occurs
    buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
    weekNumbers: true, // show week numbers
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true, // can make changes and add changes
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    displayEventTime: false, // display the start time
    displayEventEnd: false, // display the end time
    eventTimeFormat: {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
      },// display time with minutes
    eventDisplay: 'auto', //Controls which preset rendering style events use. 'block' - changes an event with start and end times from a list-item to a block
    eventConstraint: {
        start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),/* This constrains it to today or later */
        end: '2100-01-01', // hard coded goodness unfortunately
    },
    
    events: responseJson1a,//Populate Sessions/Events using JSON
```

I have added the following from Kibé M.C:

```
eventDidMount: function (info) {
//you need to get the color from "info" argument and place it on the CSS style let eventColor = info."YourEventColor"
    if (info.event) { 
        info.el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", '<p class="largeDot" style="color:${info.borderColor}">•</p>'); 
    }
},
```

I also tried:

```
style="color:${info.event.borderColor}"
```

However the dot is not picking up the 'red' from borderColor and the text drops out of the border:

[image]

Also, the 'month' and 'list' views have two dots:

[image]

Comment: So you don't want a border round timeGrid events? In that case, how will you determine the length of the event? If it's just a dot and some text, you won't be able to see where it ends. That doesn't matter so much in dayGrid and list views, because there's not intended to be any visual indication of the length of the event within a day, but in timeGrid it's pretty essential to understand what the event is doing. I think if you remove that, it will make the timeGrid view much more difficult to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eventDidMount`

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
...
 eventDidMount: function (args: any) {
        if (eventsExist) {
          args.el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", "•");
        }
      },
```

**UPDATE**
You should only see one dot.

Send a screenshot of the two dots so I try debugging the issue

You can add CSS to define a fixed size

To have dynamic colors on the dot, you can simply do this:

```
eventDidMount: function (info) 
//you need to get the color from "info" argument and place it on the CSS style 
let eventColor = info."YourEventColor"
{ if (info.event) { info.el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", `<p style="color:${eventColor}">•</p>`); 
} },
```

Comment: Hi Kibe, I get an error on "any" - Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files. I tried              eventDidMount: function (info) {
              if (eventsExist) {
               info.el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", "•");
              }
             }, and received a console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: eventsExist is not defined".

Comment: Hi Kibe, I ended up with: eventDidMount: function (info) {
              if (info.event) {
               info.el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", "•");
              }
             }, However, the dot is not the same size as when displayed with dayGridWeek, the dot does not have the correct colour, the dot is displayed with any dayGrid (e.g., dayGridMonth) resulting in two dots.

Comment: I have updated the code so you can have dynamic colors based on your events

Comment: Hi Kibe, OK this sort of works; however, I have a few issues. I have resolved most issues by changing the data I am sending from the server side to include 'backgroundColor', 'borderColor' and 'textColor'. This will allow me to give the user these options. So by setting the back ground colour to white that solves one problem. When I use your code the dor is not set to the correct colour and there is a line break. Also, the month and list views have two dot. I will update my question to provide full details.

Comment: Hi Kibe, I have resolved the line break issue by using prepend; however, I still have the issues. That is the dot is not set to the correct colour and the month and list views have two dots. The code is: `$(info.el).find('.fc-event-title').prepend("<i class='largeDot' style='color:${info.event.borderColor}'>•</i>").append("<i class='fa "+icon+"'></i>");`

Comment: You can hide ome of the two dots using CSS
If you don't mind, you can share the code through GitHub and I'll make the changes

Comment: Hi Kibé I resolved that issue by testing for dayGridMonth and not adding the dot if it is -  `if (calendar.view.type == "dayGridMonth") {`. Please see my full answer provided. Thank you for your help. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Kibe I got:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    firstDay: 0, //Sunday
    weekends: true, //Show the weekends
    hiddenDays: calendarHidenDays, //non working days to hide
    businessHours: { // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
        daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Friday
        startTime: '09:00', // a start time
        endTime: '17:00', // an end time
    },
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
    },
    locale: 'en-gb',
    selectable: true, // gives ability to select multiple days and then have a callback event when this occurs
    buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
    weekNumbers: true, // show week numbers
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true, // can make changes and add changes
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    displayEventTime: false, // display the start time
    displayEventEnd: false, // display the end time
    eventTimeFormat: {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
      },// display time with minutes
    eventDisplay: 'auto', //Controls which preset rendering style events use. 'block' - changes an event with start and end times from a list-item to a block
    eventConstraint: {
        start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),/* This constrains it to today or later */
        end: '2100-01-01', // hard coded goodness unfortunately
    },
    
    events: responseJson1a,//Populate Sessions/Events using JSON
    
    eventDidMount: function(info) {
        console.log(info.event.borderColor);
        var icon = info.event.extendedProps.icon;
        if (info.event.extendedProps.icon) {
            if (calendar.view.type == "dayGridMonth") {
                $(info.el).find('.fc-event-title').append("<i class='fa "+icon+"'></i>");
            }else {
                $(info.el).find('.fc-event-title').prepend("<i class='largeDot' style='color:"+info.event.borderColor+"'>•</i>").append("<i class='fa "+icon+"'></i>");
            }
        }else{
            //
            if (calendar.view.type != "dayGridMonth") {
                $(info.el).find('.fc-event-title').prepend("<i class='largeDot' style='color:"+info.event.borderColor+"'>•</i>");
            }
        };
    },
});
```

The variables passed back from the serverside are:

```
id, title, daysOfWeek, startRecur, endRecur, startTime, endTime, backgroundColor, classNames, extendedProps1, icon, setAllDay, borderColor, textColor
```